Capturing area of inactive/background window as image in python
How to capture specific area of inactive window in python?

it cannot bring window foreground it has to stay in the background
it cannot use screenshot method because other windows may get in the way
it has to be specific area with defined from top, left position to bottom,
right position not the whole screen

I've managed to fulfill two first conditions however I struggle with last one, here is my code
import win32gui, win32ui
from ctypes import windll
from PIL import Image

def capture_screen():
    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
   
    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, rect[2], rect[3])  # figure a way to capture only a part of the screen instead
    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)    
    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 2)
    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    image = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
    
    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)

    return image

WINDOW_NAME = 'Play Chrome Dinosaur Game Online - elgooG - Google Chrome'
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, WINDOW_NAME)

screen_capture = capture_screen()
screen_capture.save('window_capture.png')

Here is the picture being saved:
Full screen dino
Here is my goal:
Desired output

I've managed to resolve my issue by creating a NumPy array from bitmap buffer, reshaping array to represent image dimensions, then selecting desired height range
import win32gui, win32ui
import numpy as np
from ctypes import windll
from PIL import Image

def capture_screen():
    w, h = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)[2:]
    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)
    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)    
    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 2)
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
      
    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)

    img = np.frombuffer(bmpstr, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (h, w, 4)
    capture_game_screen = img[370:800]

    pil_img = Image.fromarray(capture_game_screen)

    return pil_img


WINDOW_NAME = 'Play Chrome Dinosaur Game Online - elgooG - Google Chrome'
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, WINDOW_NAME)

screen_capture = capture_screen()
screen_capture.show()

Would love to see if anyone has better memory efficient resolution

Also it is possible to select width of the array screent to by modyfing capture_game_screen like - capture_game_screen = img[top:bottom, left:right]
